# How to append an object to JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

`var table = {"abc":{0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}};`

This is my JSON array, I can access the data like  this now: `table["abc"][1]`

Now, How do I append another element like `abc` 
Something like this:

`table.append({"xyz":{0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}});`

Comment: There's no array and no json anywhere in your code.

Comment: `table["xyz"] = {0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}`

Comment: You should learn some basics: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar with the way you access it

```js
var table = {"abc":{0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}};

console.log(table["abc"][1]);

table["xyz"] = {0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0};

console.log(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

The immutable way:

```
var table = {"abc":{0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}};

table = {
   ...table,
   xyz: {
     0:0, 
     1:5, 
     2:0, 
     3:0, 
     4:0, 
     5:0, 
     6:0, 
     7:0, 
     8:0
   }
}
```

Not got Object Spread support? Try this:

```
table = Object.assign({}, table, {
  xyz: {
    0:0, 
    1:5, 
    2:0, 
    3:0, 
    4:0, 
    5:0, 
    6:0, 
    7:0, 
    8:0
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can add more data to table object

```
table.xyz = {0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}
```

its just as simple. Your new table will be as

```
var table = {"abc":{0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0},
         "xyz":{0:0, 1:5, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0}};
```

Here is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/mustkeom/pykmd60j/